# After using force:createRecord, and click on save it will navigate to newly created record... can we control this navigation or stop it?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using force:createRecord to get record creation pop up page. However, as soon as user click on save button of that popup, he is redirected to newly created record by Salesforce. 
Can we control this Or, my requirement is to keep the user on the same page.

- Raj

Comment: The popup creation record is standard, and for the moment I don't think we have extensions as we have in classic to control the standard forms. So to answer your requirement you need to create your own Lightning Component to control it all (even on Save action).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we need to create our own component as standard component is not flexible yet.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use "navigationLocation":LOOKUP.

**Below is the Code, It might help you :**

```
 // Add this below line in the function
    var LOOKUP = 'LOOKUP'; 
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
    "entityApiName": entityApiName,
     "recordTypeId": recordTypeId,
    // Add the below line
      "navigationLocation":LOOKUP
      // Add the above line
         });

     createRecordEvent.fire();
```

Comment: Can you provide documentation link as well. It seems to a hack like panelOnDestroyCallback, which was deprecated after some releases.

Comment: There is no such official Documentation link but I found that on one of the solution of Salesforce Ideas and it working fine.